# Wine Error Window Popping Up Without Further Issues

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I can run Wine apps without issues. But each time starting them up I keep getting two of the same Wine error windows ("The program (unidentified) has encountered ... and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.) that I ignore and close without further issues for the intended Wine programs. They always work. But the popping up of these windows annoy me. What's going on here? What is this 'unidentified program'? What's being 'autostarted' along with the program that temporarily hicks up Wine and probably delays the intended program start? This is just one thing that has been going on for months. No other issues.

Ubuntu 14.04, 2GB ram, 32bit